# Add action Buttons on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" tabStyle="Opportunity">
<apex:form >
<apex:sectionHeader title="Opportunity Edit" subtitle="New Opportunity"/>
<apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Details">
 <apex:pageBlockButtons >
   <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save"/>
   <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
 </apex:pageBlockButtons>  
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I want to add 'Save & New' action button on my vf page. I'm currently using 'Save' button, is it possible..?

Comment: are you takling about apex:CommanButton name only or you want New page also after save ?

Comment: I'm just considering <apex:commandButton> .. after saving record page will be redirected to same page

Comment: you can have value="Save & New" .
if you are looking apart from rename, then please show your code.

Comment: <apex:page standardController="Opportunity" tabStyle="Opportunity">
<apex:form >
<apex:sectionHeader title="Opportunity Edit" subtitle="New Opportunity"/>
<apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Details">
 <apex:pageBlockButtons >
   <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save"/>
   <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
 </apex:pageBlockButtons>  
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>

Code is something like this...I want to add one more button 'Save & new'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write custom code for that. You can use and `Save method` to save record and after that redirect your user to same page.

```
Public pagereference saveNew()
{
  //Save the data here
  Pagereference pr = new Pagereference('/apex/YourCustomVFPage');
  pr.setRedirect(true);
  return pr;
}
```

and then you can call your method from VF page

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save and New" action="{!saveNew}" />
```

Comment: @AtulRakate you need to use  extension for that. You can use `standardController.Save()` here